# Got $request->isXmlHttpRequest() always false

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, symfony

i want to persist an entity and catch a message with ajax (without Jquery), but i got troubles with boolean  $request->isXmlHttpRequest() .

The script here :

```
var xhr = getXMLHttpRequest(); 

xhr.open("POST", "{{ path('deplacement') }}", true);
xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
xhr.send("coordonnee="+abs+"-"+ord+"&name="+personnage[0].getAttribute('id'));

xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (xhr.readyState == 4 && (xhr.status == 200 || xhr.status == 0)) {
        var classPersonnage = personnage[0].getAttribute('class');
        var arrayClassPersonnage = classPersonnage.split(' ');
        var id = personnage[0].getAttribute('id');
        personnage[0].removeAttribute('class');
        var newClass= '';
        for (i=0; i < arrayClassPersonnage.length-1; i++){
            newClass= newClass+' '+arrayClassPersonnage[i];
        }
        document.getElementById(id).setAttribute('class', newClass);
        var resultat = JSON.parse(xhr.responseText);
        alert(resultat['message']);
    }
```

My controller php here

```
/**
 * @Route("/game/combat/test", name="deplacement")

 */
public function deplacementAction(Request $request){

    if($request->isXmlHttpRequest())
    {
        $response = new JsonResponse();         
        return $response->setData(array('message' => 'Ok.'));
    }
    else{
        $response = new JsonResponse();         
        return $response->setData(array('message' => 'false'));
    }
}
```

I got always 'false'. I tried to do this :

```
$response = new JsonResponse();
return $response->setData(array('message' => 'Ok.'));
```

So without $request->isXmlHttpRequest(), but i catch a internal error server 500. Please help me, i become crazy.

Comment: Maybe check that you have closed all the `}`

Comment: If you dont show us real code that runs, we end up picking the silly mistakes up and missing the big picture

Comment: All the } are closed. I post a easier example in another post but got the same mistake.

Answer (score 1):

Checking what a method does looking at its code is always helpful to find solutions to your code issues. If you check `isXmlHttpRequest` method you can see in its dockblock something like this:

> It works if your JavaScript library sets an X-Requested-With HTTP header

And method body is:

```
return 'XMLHttpRequest' == $this->headers->get('X-Requested-With');
```

Then you need to add the right header (which is added by default by most JS frameworks/libraries, for example see [jQuery](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/#jQuery-ajax-settings) scrolling to `headers` section):

```
xhr.setRequestHeader("X-Requested-With", "XMLHttpRequest");
```

Comment: I always see xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"); for the POST méthod. What's wrong with it ?

Comment: That's ok (no need to touch it), you have to add `X-Requested-With` header as well.

Comment: I was under the impression this header was actually added by the low-level `XMLHttpRequest` rather than in higher-level libraries/frameworks that use it, isn’t that the case?

Comment: @jcaron nope `X-Requested-With` is just a header convention, its not part of XHR spec.

Answer (score 0):

I try an easier example and got the same mistake. I click the button and i want the message.

Here the button and the script :

```
<button onclick="affichage()">Appuyer</button>
<script>
    function affichage(){
        if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
        { 
            xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
        } 
        else  if (window.ActiveXObject)
        {
            xhr = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
        }

        xhr.onreadystatechange  = function() 
        { 
           if(xhr.readyState  == 4)
           {
                 if(xhr.status  == 200) 
                 {
                    var resultat = JSON.parse(xhr.responseText);
                    alert(resultat['message']); 
                 }
                 else
                {
                    alert('Erreur');
                }
           }
        }; 

        xhr.open("POST", "{{ path('deplacement') }}", true);
        xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
        xhr.send(null);



    }
</script>
```

And here the file with path('deplacement') :

```
<?php

namespace GameBundle\Controller;

use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller;
use Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\Configuration\Route;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\JsonResponse;

class ResolutionController extends Controller
{
/**
 * @Route("/game/combat/test", name="deplacement")
 */
public function deplacementAction(Request $request){

    $request = $this->get('request');

    if($request->isXmlHttpRequest())
    {
        $response = new JsonResponse();

        return $response->setData(array('message' => 'Ok.'));


    }
    else{

        $response = new JsonResponse();

        return $response->setData(array('message' => $request->isXmlHttpRequest()));

    }
}

}
```

I got the error with the xhr.send(null) : failed to load resource  the serveur responde with a status of 500.

I just want to got this one to correct the real code.

Comment: Please edit your original post with updates to your original question, don’t post them as answers.

Comment: You should post this as another question. People dont look for questions in Answers